# Gummy Bear Digital Drawing Critique

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing, critique, digital

[image]

How can I do a better job next time I draw this gummy bear? I am going for photo realism.

Tools: photoshop (the latest version), Wacom Cintiq 22HD

My process was:

- beginning with a box to understand the orientation of the bear
- using cones and spheres and other basic shapes to make the form more specific
- beginning with a base red
- adding shadows by playing with saturation
- coloring over everything a few times with a 30% opacity very saturated red
- using the eraser tool to create the translucent areas of the gummy
- adding highlights

Comment: Hi Jenny! Can you give us some more details? For example, what have you already tried? What techniques did you use to render this image? What software are you using? The more details we have the easier it will be for us to answer your question. :)

Comment: No problem! will edit and add those details

Comment: suggestion: check google for photos of real gummy bears. You'll notice that sometimes it's easier to see the shape and transparency when the gummy is in certain positions (took me a while to see the bear shape in your drawing).

Answer (score 5):

You did well in creating the dimensionality of the gummi bear, but one aspect that I feel did not come through as well is the transparency.  It might have been the specific lightning you were copying, but more contrast between the light and dark parks would help give it a more transparent and shiny look.